# How to know if the the current activity has been refreshed android?

Tags: android

I want to a task once.
but when i recreate everything is started from start.
so how to know the current activity has been refreshed.
maybe something like
hasrefreshed();

Comment: Do you mean if the onResume is called multiple times?

Comment: This may not be the specific answer you need but will help you ask a specific question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85MppyLJHz0

Comment: no if whole activity has been recreated